# 'oTrans' is not a member of 'Script'

Tags: epicor10

I encountered this really bizarre error in Epicor. I was trying to modify my tree options and I encountered the error 'oTrans' is not a member of 'Script' upon saving the tree options. I tried to check the customization code but by default oTrans is already instantiated in the custom code. Is this a known bug in Epicor? I am currently using Epicor 10.1.

Comment: I know this is 6 months old, but what screen are/were you modifying? Some screens in Epicor do not use transactions.

Comment: Hey @JosephMoeller! Nice to have someone that i could have a discussion with regarding this issue. I am navigating the Project Entry module and trying to display the task description together with the task number on the tree options.

Comment: Okay great! Can you post the problem portion of your code in a code block in the question?  I might try to reproduce on my side and find the best way to recommend you solve your issue.